# In which package is Flink DataGen SQL Connector

Tags: java, maven, apache-flink, flink-sql

In which Maven package is [Flink DataGen SQL Connector](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/table/datagen/)?

I often find examples [like this one](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/common/) with an **import** statement but it's not specified anywhere in which package, in this particular case searching Maven or search engines didn't yield a result either.

Here is a picture of the error that I get:
[image: Cannot resolve symbol datagen]

Flink packages in pom.xml are:

```
flink-java
flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}
flink-clients_${scala.binary.version}
flink-statebackend-rocksdb_2.11
flink-table-api-java
flink-sql-client_2.11
flink-test-utils_2.11
```

I also tried including:

```
flink-connector-base
flink-connector-jdbc_2.12
flink-connector-kafka-base_2.11
```

But it still can't resolve the import and TableDescriptor.forConnector.

Comment: In case you using Flink version 1.15 there is no more `${scala.binary.version}` in the dependencies check [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-clients/1.15.1) and [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/release-notes/flink-1.15/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to do some digging but I found the docs for doing it in a way that works with the version that I have:
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/connectors/table/datagen/

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE GenOrders
WITH (
    'connector' = 'datagen',
    'number-of-rows' = '10'
)
LIKE ...
```

I'm sorry that I didn't mention the Flink version but it is 1.13.

Answer (score 2):

> The DataGen connector is built-in, no additional dependencies are
> required.

Look [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/table/datagen/)

Comment: If it's built in then why am I getting errors.

Comment: Check the dependency versions.

Comment: Ok, I see that the docs for the other connectors have a dependency section. @Metehan thank you

Comment: I guess it solves my question although it didn't solve my problem, thank you for answering.